# A faster way of building a Pandas.Dataframe from list of dictionaries than loop? [Python 3.9]

Tags: python, pandas, list, performance, dictionary

I have a list of 5000 dictionaries where each dictionary has around 40 items, I have built a `for` loop that is extreeeemly slow - it needs a couple of minutes.

```
        # symbol_list_final is the list of dictionaries
        symbols_dataframe = pd.DataFrame([symbols_list_final[0]])

        for i in range(len(symbols_list_final) - 1):
             symbol_df_temp = pd.DataFrame([symbols_list_final[i + 1]])
             symbols_dataframe = pd.concat((symbols_dataframe, symbol_df_temp), axis=1)
             print(i)
```

Is there any way of doing it faster?

EDIT: It's way slower, My program is running rn, and it takes 1 seconds to make 4-5 iterations.

Comment: Concatenate all your dictionaries in a single step: `pd.concat(your_list_of_dictionaries)`. Don't re-concatenate; every time you do so, Pandas allocates a new data frame.

Comment: @ifly6 I dont think concat can take dict objects

Comment: @ifly6 it did not, I have just typed 'symbols_dataframe = pd.DataFrame(symbols_list_final)'
and it worked. 
You have placed me on the right path nonetheless. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seen like you are trying to formulate multiple dict dataframes and concatenate then into a single variable, containing your end_df.
Firstly, the correct approach envolves not concatenating them all the time, only running such command once. So would recommend stacking the df objects on a list, and them concatenating

```
list_of_dfs = []
for i in list_dict:
    list_of_dfs.append(pd.DataFrame(i))
```

So `pd.concat(list_of_dfs )` would be wise than redefining your variable all the time in your loop

Now if creating the df object is taking a while (give us the time). Well there are other ways of approaching this issue, such as  the library pyarrow (which can be faster depending on your cpu).